# iPad and mobile issue with large image

Tags: iphone, css, ios, ipad

I currently have an image on my site which is a lot larger than usual, but the website cuts off the image at each side dependant on the width of each users monitor, which is fine.

However, on an iPad/mobile device, the whole image is always showing, which is pushing the whole site to the left and also leaving a large area of white space to the right.

Any advice on how to ensure the iPad cuts off the image as the web browsers are doing would be appreciated.

I have used the following in my header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=980px">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980">
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to your web page?

Comment: try initial-scale=1. Anyways there is always a problem with meta viewport. Check the discussion here: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1099

Comment: I have managed to get the image to fit onto the screen now, although the image is squashed to fit the screen rather than cut off

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the time of your of definition of UIWebView

```
webView.frame=self.view.bounds;

webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

So user will zoom in and zoom out according to his/her need to read the content.